# Centering embedded pdf in a div

Tags: css

Having a bit of trouble centering an embedded pdf within a div.

This is my HTML code snippet.

```
<div id="splash">
    <div class="post">
    <h2>Heading </h2>
        <p><embed src="images/dop.pdf" ALIGN=CENTER width="820" height="375"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the relevant CSS from my style.css file:

```
#splash {
padding: 40px;
position: relative;
background: #FFF;
margin: 20px 0 0 0;
height: 300px;
width: 1100px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}

.post {

margin-left: auto ;
margin-right: auto ;
}

p {
margin-bottom: 1.75em;
margin-left: auto ;
margin-right: auto ;    
}
```

To my knowledge, setting the margin-left and margin-right to auto should center what's in the div in either the `post` class or the `<p>` tag.  So why is the .pdf is staying on the left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your `<div class="post">` an explicit width.

E.g.:

```
.post {
width: 820px;
margin-left: auto ;
margin-right: auto ;
}
```

Setting the left and right margins to auto only will work if the width is less than 100% of the parent element. Otherwise, being a block element, the div will expand to the fullest possible width. Also note that `ALIGN=CENTER` is old and deprecated and shouldn't be used.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/YYL7C/)**

Comment: I've done this, removed ALIGN=CENTER, and got rid of the margins in my <p> - but the pdf is still stuck over on the left.  Any other suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?  The only other parent element is a wrapper div which goes over everything

Comment: Are you saying that it didn't work for you? As you can see by the jsFiddle example is works fine unless you have other CSS affecting the layout.

Comment: On the jsFiddle, if you change for example the width of the embedded document to 400, it's still aligned left under 'Heading'.  What I'm looking for is how to align it in the center, as it has to be narrower than the page.  Does that make sense?

Comment: If you change the width of the embed, change the with of .post to match it. Or just rid of the width on the embed and set it on the .post.

Answer (score 1):

The inner `<div>` (`post`) needs a `width`. Otherwise it will fill 100% of the surrounding element (`splash`).

Answer (score 1):

Setting both side margins to auto won't do anything if your element has 100% width, as all `div`s do by default.  If you specify a width, then the *remaining* horizontal space will be evenly split by the left and right margins.  Example:

```
.post { width: 500px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
```

Note that the auto margins on your `p` probably aren't working for the same reason; you could probably remove that specification.